# Como graficar datos en python usando tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

como se encuentran.

Tengo el siguiente problema, en el cual estoy mostrando valores cada determinado tiempo en un Entry usando Tkinter, los cuales funcionan adecuadamente, y estuve tratando de generar una gráfica para poder plotear todos los datos nuevos que se generan pero solo me aparece la gráfica pero no se plotean los datos, si alguien pudiera ayudarme en este problema, estoy trabajando de igual manera con sensores de temperatura y una raspberry para generar las gráficas, pero en este programa estoy generando los valores al azar y actualizándolos cada segundo.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.lines as lines
from scipy import integrate
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import tkinter

def imou():
    humidity = random.uniform(0, 10)

    # Cambio el contenido del entry a traves del stringvar.
    sv.set(humidity)


    # Le digo a Tkinter que ejecute la función dentro de un segundo.
    # Vos podes hacer que se ejecute con más frecuencia.
    # Si analisas esto, hace que la función se ejecute cada segundo.
    win.after(1000, imou)


    
def imou1():
    pressure = random.uniform(0, 10)

    # Cambio el contenido del entry a traves del stringvar.
    sv1.set(pressure)

    # Le digo a Tkinter que ejecute la función dentro de un segundo.
    # Vos podes hacer que se ejecute con más frecuencia.
    # Si analisas esto, hace que la función se ejecute cada segundo.
    win.after(1000, imou1)
    
def imou2():
    ambient_temperature = random.uniform(0, 10)
    
    # Cambio el contenido del entry a traves del stringvar.
    sv2.set(ambient_temperature)

    # Le digo a Tkinter que ejecute la función dentro de un segundo.
    # Vos podes hacer que se ejecute con más frecuencia.
    # Si analisas esto, hace que la función se ejecute cada segundo.
    win.after(1000, imou2)
    
win = Tk()

# Creo el StringVar que asociaré a este entry
sv = StringVar()

# Creo el entry y enlaso el StringVar con este
e = Entry(win,width=10, textvariable=sv)
e.pack()
# Actualizo el entry inmediatamente
imou()


# Creo el StringVar que asociaré a este entry
sv1 = StringVar()
# Creo el entry y enlaso el StringVar con este
e1 = Entry(win,width=10, textvariable=sv1)
e1.pack()
# Actualizo el entry inmediatamente
imou1()


# Creo el StringVar que asociaré a este entry
sv2 = StringVar()
# Creo el entry y enlaso el StringVar con este
e2 = Entry(win,width=10, textvariable=sv2)
e2.pack()
# Actualizo el entry inmediatamente
imou2()


humidity = random.uniform(0, 10)
x8 = []
x8.append(humidity)

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
#t = np.arange(0, 1, 1)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(humidity)#AÑADIR "subbplot"

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=win)  # CREAR AREA DE DIBUJO DE TKINTER.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, win)# barra de iconos
toolbar.update()

mainloop()
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, saludos